# java. Что означает слово other

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, что в данном коде значит слово otherMatrix. IMatrix - это интерфейс для работы с матрицами.

```
public IMatrix add(IMatrix otherMatrix) throws IllegalArgumentException,
       NullPointerException                       {     
    double[][] result = new double[this.getRows()][this.getColumns()];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.getColumns(); j++) {
        result[i][j] = this.matrix[i][j] + otherMatrix.getValueAt(i, j);
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(result);
}
```

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: otherMatrix - это имя переменной. Вы знаете что такое интерфейс, но не знаете что такое переменная??

Comment: otherMatrix  - это не переменная:)

Comment: @KoVadim окей, это параметр, а в чем по вашему отличие от переменной? в контексте метода.

Comment: Вы действительно не видите разницы и хотите ее узнать? Задавайте отдельный вопрос, посмотрим на минусы:)

Comment: @KoVadim, а если совсем кратко?..

Comment: Параметр - частный случай переменной, блин.

Answer (score 4):

`otherMatrix` - это просто параметр метода `add`.

Более детальнее - когда Вы будете вызывать метод add, Вам нужно передать ещё одну матрицу, с которой будете складывать.